# Get floating point division in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, division

In shell script I have variable `a=20` and `b=100`, I want to perform divison a/b in shell. I don't want to use external command like `bc` or other. `awk` may work. But it throws error like

```
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: division by zero attempted
```

How can I perform this division in shell?

Comment: Please add your code and your desired output to your question.

Comment: `python -c "print($a/$b)"`

Comment: You're okay with awk but not bc?

Comment: Use ksh or zsh instead of bash. Both support native floating point math operations.

Comment: Are `a` and `b` always integers?

Comment: Ya both of them will be integers

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to do floating point arithmetic in bash, but you can do this with awk:

```
a=20 b=100
awk "BEGIN {print($a/$b)}"
```

Or a little more elegant (thank you, Cyrus):

```
awk -v a=20 -v b=100 'BEGIN {print(a/b)}'
```

Comment: I want to print c=0.2. how can I do that?

Comment: I mean ,I will have a=20 b=100. And console output must be c=0.2

Comment: `c=$(awk -v a=20 -v b=100 'BEGIN {print(a/b)}'); echo "c=$c"`

Comment: or just `awk -v a=20 -v b=100 'BEGIN {print "c="a/b}'` depending on what you really need.

Comment: Thanks. it worked